# How to move nested elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested

I'm trying to move nested lists. When the parent is selected, the children should be moved as well. When a child is selected the parent should be copied and the child moved, so the structure is kept. Someone can point me in the right direction, when i start coding its get overly complex.

Here is an example is used, without nesting.
http://jsfiddle.net/EEhbQ/

html:

```
 <ul id="select1">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />Checkbox 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Checkbox 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />Checkbox 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="select2">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_0" />Checkbox 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_1" />Checkbox 5</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_2" />Checkbox 6</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="add">add</a>
<a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#select1 li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/EEhbQ/18/

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    return !$('#select1 li :checked').closest('ul').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function () {
    return !$('#select2 li :checked').closest('ul').prependTo('body');
});
```